# predicting X values from smooth.spline

Tags: r, prediction, splines, smoothing

I have an existing `smooth.spline` object, and I wish to estimate X values for a set of new Y values. I see that `predict.smooth.spline` exists, but for predicting Y for new Xs.

Are there methods for predicting X from Y? (Apparently this is common in biomedical fields when working with standard curves for blood assay concentrations).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please see our threads on [inverse regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22inverse+regression%22) and [calibration](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibration+regression).  You may refine these searches with additional keywords such as "spline" or "score:1" (to eliminate any post with no net upvotes).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find anything relevant under those tags. Apparently GraphPad Prism's smoothing spline offers this functionality but I haven't found any documentation on what methods it uses. If anyone has any other suggestions I'd appreciate it.